# Get pytest autocompletion in zshell

Tags: python, autocomplete, zsh, pytest

This question may be better suited for superuser -- if that's the case let me know and I'll shift it.

I use zsh and frequently run pytest from the command line. A very common situation is that I need to run a specific test (or a subtest of a class).

The former looks something like

`pytest test/test_foo_file.py::test_foo_function`

and the latter something like

`pytest test/test_foo_file.py::FooClassTest::test_specific_functionality`

It's kind of a pain to write out the entire exact class and test name, and this seems like something ripe for autocompletion or fuzzysearching of some kind. I've been unable to achieve this with what I've found researching -- does anyone have any recommendations?

Let me know if I can be more specific in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am not a `zsh` user, but the approach is pretty much similar to the customizing of bash completions:

1. Create a custom completion file, e.g.

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/.zsh-completions
   $ touch ~/.zsh-completions/_pytest
   ```
2. Inside `~/.zsh-completions/_pytest`, write the completion function:

   ```
   #compdef pytest

   _pytest_complete() {
       local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
       typeset -A opt_args
       compadd "$@" $( pytest --collect-only -q | head -n -2)
   }

   _pytest_complete "$@"
   ```
3. Adjust `.zshrc` to include custom completions, e.g.

   ```
   fpath=(~/.zsh-completions $fpath)
   autoload -U compinit
   compinit
   zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
   ```

Restart the shell. Now you should get the single tests selection on tab completion:

[image]

The crucial command here is

```
$ pytest --collect-only -q | head -n -2
```

which collects the tests in current directory and lists their names ready to be passed as command line arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Im going to try it later (currently afk) and will mark as correct assuming it works :)

Comment: Hey @hoefling, thanks again. This largely worked, so I'm going to mark as correct. One minor issue -- it's very slow. It takes ~5-10 seconds to load the menu of possible tests -- is this something you've experienced? Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, depending on how many tests you have, test collection can get very slow. If the collect command from above is slow when you run it explicitly (e.g. `time pytest --collect-only -q`), then the completions will also be slow.

Comment: Damn, got it. Maybe I can somehow cache and pre optimize. Thank you!!

Comment: Did you optimize it or cache it ? If yes, can you explain how ? I am very interested :)

Answer (score 0):

Like others in the comments, I have noticed that `pytest --collect-only -q` takes a long time to load.

As an alternative, I wrote my own pytest function collector which is much faster.

```
#compdef pytest

function quick_collect_pytests {
    RES=$(rg "^def (test_.*)\(" --no-heading)

    IFS=$'\n'
    for res in $RES; do
      echo $res | awk '{
        if (match($0, /(.*test_.*):def (.*)\(/, groups)) {
          print groups[1] "::" groups[2]
        }
      }'
    done
}

_pytest_complete() {
    local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
    typeset -A opt_args
    compadd "$@" $( quick_collect_pytests)
}
_pytest_complete "$@"
```

Feel free to give it a go and let me know if you see any potential improvements.