# pytest autocompletion in Bash

Tags: bash, pytest, bash-completion

I am hoping to get Bash autocompletion to work with pytest. That is, suppose that I have a pytest file `test_foo.py` whose content is

```
def test_case_simple():
  pass
```

then entering `pytest test_foo.py::` and pressing tab would give me `test_case_simple`. I know that [Get pytest autocompletion in zshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044327/get-pytest-autocompletion-in-zshell) is a related question but I am unable to get the same script working for bash (it gives me an error saying that `compadd` is unknown).

---

Followup: The script that I used is

```
#compdef pytest

_pytest_complete() {
    local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
    typeset -A opt_args
    compadd "$@" $( pytest --collect-only -q | head -n -2)
}

_pytest_complete "$@"
```

and the error I got is

```
compadd: command not found
```

Comment: please post your script and errors you hit.

Comment: @pynexj Information updated.

Comment: bash does not have a `compadd` command.

Comment: @pynexj Yes. I know. That script is for zsh and I am wondering whether there is an equivalent command for bash so that I could use the above script for pytest autocompletion in bash.

Comment: bash has its own commands for completion. see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins